# Should we allow comment deletion after a set time?

Tags: discussion, comments

During a fairly heated exchange regarding this question

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41802/is-there-any-restrictions-on-driving-a-private-car-from-the-uk-to-the-african-co?noredirect=1#comment77517_41802

A number of user posted comments which were not constructive and quite snarky.  I have fairly thick skin and such things don't really bother me however the subsequent rebuttal comments by other posters, which took time to craft, now make no sense and are a complete waste of time and effort.

As well as the waste the conversation has absolutely no context or narrative for anyone else coming to the question to read it.

In addition, allowing comment deletion lets users post insults, baiting comments or other type activities and then delete the comment after having trolled the question or answer.

Should we limit the timeframe for comment deletion?

Comment: The answer to the original question and sharing or not is not relevant to this question; you are simply obfuscating.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are suggesting that comment deletion be prevented when they are old or when they are new, but I would not recommend it either way.  If a comment is meaningless or disruptive or very very wrong, it should be deletable at any time.

Answer (score 6):

When people have removed their comments, it's always possible (and indeed very common) to flag the out-of-context comments for mods to 'clean up' the conversation.

Also be very careful not to get dragged into 'snarky' debates - if someone says something offensive, flag it for a mod, but do NOT 'return fire' :) (This isn't aimed at you or anyone in particular, more for future readers of this thread).

The timeframe isn't controllable by the mods on Travel.SE.  It may be something worth posting on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as a feature-request, but considering the number of times I've added a comment and realised in 30 seconds that I'd misunderstood, so removed my comment, I don't expect it's something that'd be implemented.